# Using images from my server on a remote webpages

Tags: php, mysql, image-gallery

I have many images on my server, possibly over 4000. All images are taken from soccer games that my kids team has played in. Other teams want to use them on many different remote webpages. They want to be able to easily create a gallery on their own webpage using images from my server. This has to be really easy for them to make because they are not developers. Can someone please point me in the right direction how this can be done?

My server consists of:

Ubuntu Server 16.04, MySQL, PHP, Jquery, Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use API on your server and create JSON code. so they can call your API server and request the images.

Comment: I understand what you mean. It feels like a interesting solution. Can you please elaborate with a simple example?

Comment: ok, so you had and image data which you can decode it into JSON using php. afterward the web pages that request your image data call your API from your server or your website.